# How to commit and rollback commands work in updating a table of records in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, commit, rollback

I know the concepts of commit and rollback in update statement, but trying those concepts in MySQL I stuck at one point i.e I can't rollback the previous records of content where I saved them by using commit statement.

```
use employees;

select * from employees
where emp_no = '999903' ; #Here The Row Is Empty So I Inserted New Data

insert into employees
set 
 emp_no = '999903',
 birth_date = '1997-02-09',
 first_name = 'Shon',
 last_name = 'Frost',
 gender = 'M',
 hire_date = '2019-07-25' ;

insert into titles # titles is child table where related to employees which describes about the position of employee
set
 emp_no = '999903',
 title = 'Data Scientist',
 from_date = '2019-07-25' ;

commit ;

delete from employees
where emp_no = '999903' ;

rollback ;
```

The error I'm getting is `Null Data`. After selecting the specific data even though I used rollback command properly and MySQL shows the code is perfect with 0 errors and 0 warnings.

I am expecting the result of data that what I entered.
Could you please advise me?

Comment: the `start transaction` is missing, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html it says "By default, MySQL runs with autocommit mode enabled. This means that as soon as you execute a statement that updates (modifies) a table, MySQL stores the update on disk to make it permanent. The change cannot be rolled back. "

Comment: You can't `ROLLBACK` if you've already applied a `COMMIT`. You need to open a new transaction, or use a [`SAVEPOINT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/savepoint.html) for subtransactions.

Comment: Is "auto-commit" enabled? It's usually enabled by default. You can disable it by starting a transaction.